# how to scroll image on mouse over?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've done a website http://www.chitarrastudio.com/, as you can see on the top there are two guitars, one classic and a gibson.

I want to realize an effect: when the mouse is hover, a guitar or the other slide down, up to appear completely(by clicking on it, there is a link).

In short, it is the same effect of many menus on the websites: as here, passing on "Perhier."  http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/cool-menu/.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Are your guitars images? If so you can use css transition to animate the guitars up and down. if I understand you right.

Comment: yes! and how can i do this?

Comment: Just wondering if some people try to google or write something by themselves before just asking here.. it's sad cause ppl here tryhard for rep so they answer even if the asking person doesn't show any effort...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this with jquery:

Example: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/MhNUT/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("img").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: '0px'
        }, 'slow');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: '-100'
        }, 'slow');
    });

});
```

Comment: Just the last thing: how can i put a link? I want clicking on the guitar there is a link

Comment: Something like this <a href="yourlink"><img src="http://www.learninghub.ie/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/steps-to-a-clean-electric-guitar.jpg" width="200" height="" /></a>

Comment: I update my Fiddle example and put a link for google.com if you click in the guitar.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with all the answer's here, as this can be done with CSS only.

```
img {
    position:relative;
    top:-100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

img:hover {
    top:0;
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TyBHu/

Comment: This should ideally be an accepted answer, as it is coming with pure CSS and was the category which was tagged in when the OP asked the question. Nevertheless +1 from me :)

Comment: She accepted a Jquery answer before the CSS one was posted - she was obviously was looking for a general solution and not a strict CSS one . You'd had advise to edit tags.

Comment: @AlexGarulli That doesn't change the fact that a CSS solution is (almost) always better then a jQuery solution. You can write fallback's for older browser's with jQuery but CSS animations are much (much much much) better. If it's possible with CSS, use CSS.

Comment: I think the OP should be more responsive in this, as she had mentioned a css tag, which no doubt holds importance and should have been considered by users answering the question. There are people who present another solution which may or may not define the tag, which is their personal choice and will, but it is finally only the OP who has the right to accept whatever they want, but in my personal opinion, this should have been accepted.

Comment: I agree that the user wasn't really specific about what kind of solution he was looking for. But the post is tagged with CSS, so in that case you can assume (in my opinion) that he prefer's a CSS solution. I think the OP didn't read my answer yet. Stackoverflow is about finding the best solution for coding problem's and in my opinion my answer is better then the other answer's.

Comment: guys you were all absolutly perfect. i searched for weeks in my country, without results. and here... in something like 5 minuts so many people helped me. thank you!! really, i'm glad. for me it's the same, jquery or css. the important thing is that you helped me, and this is great

Comment: Why i can't define the position of those images? http://jsfiddle.net/TyBHu/ what's wrong?

Comment: what u mean define the position? try position: absolute and then top left

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use transform property. Check out this [codepen.io pen](https://codepen.io/ouzkagan/pen/RwaPGej)

```css
/* Extra */
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.center{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  gap: 25px;
}
.frame{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ff1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.card .title{
  text-align:center;
}

/* Hover Scroll Effect */
.frame{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.frame img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: 2s ease-out;
}
.frame:hover img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  /* Considering frame height   */
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 300px));
  transition: 2s ease-out;
}
/*OR */
/* .frameimg:hover{
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: 2s ease-out;
} */

/* With background image  */
.bg-image{

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/500x1500/);
  transition: background-position 2s ease-out;
  
}
.frame:hover .bg-image{
    background-position: 0 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="frame">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x1500/" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Made with img tag</h3>
    <p>You need to consider frame height</p>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="bg-image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>made with background image</h3>
        <p>Make <code/>background-position: 0 100%</code> on hover</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```